# OpenGL/OpenCV Camera rendering in pyqt4 on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, opengl, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I am trying to render camera feed (Taken from OpenCV) from a usb webcam to a pyqt window using OpenGL, and this is all on a raspberry pi.

Before this I was drawing the feed to the screen by simply converting each frame to a QImage and then changing a QLabel's pixmap to the new frame every update. This, however, is proving to be too slow, especially considering the limited power of the raspberry pi. I need the feed to be as fast as possible. By fast, I mean that the delay between the camera feed and actual actions in real life needs to minimal(<500ms) With the Qlabel method, the display lagged about 1000-1500ms whish is way too slow.

I am trying to get all of this working together and I am having several problems.

1. If I try to run any python program that uses OpenGL over SSH on X-ming, it imediately crashes.
2. When I run [this](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/316) test OpenGL program directly from the pi, it runs correctly but gives me a blank window as apposed to the spiral picture at the bottom of that code.
3. When I run my program that gets camera output and tries to paint it with my re-implementation of paintGL(), the region of the QGLWidget fails to update. However, the camera light comes on.

Code for my QGLWidget:

```
class Ui_CameraCanvas(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self)
        self.video = Video(cv2.VideoCapture(-1))
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.play)
        self._timer.start(27)
        self.update()
        self.parWidget = parent
        self.qframe = None
    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        if (not(self.qframe.isNull())):
            self.qframe = self.qframe.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation);
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluOrtho2D(0,self.qframe.width(),self.qframe.height(),0);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, self.qframe.width(), self.qframe.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.qframe.bits() );
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0,self.qframe.height());
            glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(self.qframe.width(),0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(self.qframe.width(),self.qframe.height());
            glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glFlush();
    def resizeGL(self, w, h):      
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(40.0, 1.0, 1.0, 30.0)    
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    def initializeGL(self):
        # set viewing projection
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(40.0, 1.0, 1.0, 30.0)

    def resetCamera(self):
        try: 
            self._timer.timeout.disconnect() 
        except:
            pass
        del self.video

        pass
    def play(self):
        try:
            self.video.captureNextFrame()
            self.qframe = self.video.convertFrame()
        except TypeError:
            print "No frame"
```

Code for the Camera device that gets the feed:

```
class Video():
    def __init__(self,capture):
        self.capture = capture
        self.currentFrame=np.array([])

    def captureNextFrame(self):
        """                                          
        capture frame and reverse RBG BGR and return opencv image                                                                         
        """
        ret, readFrame=self.capture.read()
        if(ret==True):
            self.currentFrame=cv2.cvtColor(readFrame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    def convertFrame(self):
        """                                                    converts frame to format suitable for QtGui            """
        try:
            height,width=self.currentFrame.shape[:2]
            img=QtGui.QImage(self.currentFrame,
                              width,
                              height,
                              QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            img=QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
            self.previousFrame = self.currentFrame
            return img
        except:
            return None
```

I am starting to think that OpenGL is just not working on the Raspberry pi. Any suggestions for getting this to work?